# how to loop through block_blob_service.copy_blob in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am copying files from an URL to azure blob using for loop, my problem I don't know how to tell to the function to wait till the operation is completed before starting the next one

Currently I am using this workaround

```
import re
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='xxxxx',
                                      account_key='xxxxxxxxxx')
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
container_name ='yyyyyyyyyyy'



url = "http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Current/Daily_Reports/"
result = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.]*.zip')
filelist = pattern.findall(result )
for x in filelist:
      block_blob_service.copy_blob(container_name,x,url+x)
      time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little better solution is to use `get_blob_properties` method on the destination blob to check the status of the copy operation.

You can check the `copy_blob` source code as screenshot below:

[image]

So in your for loop code, you can write something like below:

```
for x in filelist:
    block_blob_service.copy_blob(container_name,x,url+x)
    copy_status = block_blob_service.get_blob_properties(container_name,x)

    #use code below to check the copy status, if it's completed or not.
    while(str(copy_status.properties.copy.status) != "success"):
        copy_status = block_blob_service.get_blob_properties(container_name,x)
```

BTW:
And also you can note there is a `requires_sync` parameter for copy_blob method, if it's assigned to True, then the copy operation is a sync operation which can make sure the next one will wait until the previous one is completed. But currently it's only available for copy blobs(both from and to) for blobs on azure storage account, not support the 3rd party url like you used in the post.

Comment: another question, what's the best service to run this kind if script on azure

Comment: @Mim, I'm not very clear the question, can you explain more details?

Comment: I run this script in my laptop and it works great, if i have to automate this script and run it in the cloud let's say 3 times a day, what service do you suggest

Comment: @Mim, you can take a try scheduled [webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) .